# How to increase users periodially in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

My test case is Users starts from **1000** and in next 1 hour there will be **10k** users on website.

I am confuse that how can I increase users in jmeter so when test reach at 1 hour, I can see 10k active users.

Should I use ultimate thread group for this? I just want hint from expert to go to next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i have understood, you want to have 1000 users immediately, then slowly 9000 users in the next 1 hr, so that you will have 10000 users.

Then `ultimate thread group` seems to be a good choice for this exact requirement.

`Hold Load for sec` is the test duration with 10000 users. adjust accordingly.

[image]

Or, if your requirement is just to have 10000 users in 1 hr, (not 1000 in the beginning) , you can also use regular thread group.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted to confirm :)

Comment: Should I not set 3600 as duration? You have set 3600 as ramp up?

Comment: 3600 is 1 hr for ramping up 10000 users.